# Prove $ab + ab\overline{c} + bcd = b(a+c)(a+d)$

Tags: self-learning, boolean-algebra

Do I need to use absorbtion law to prove them?

1. $ab + ab\overline{c} + bcd = b(a+c)(a+d)$
2. $ab + cd = (a+c)(a+d)(b+c)(b+d)$.

For 1), I simplified $ab+ ab\overline{c} + bcd$ into $b(a\overline{c} + cd)$, then I get stuck.

For 2), I found that if I expand $(a+c)(a+d)(b+c)(b+d)$, I will not be able to obtain $ab+cd$, what should I do?

Comment: If you're just supposed to _verify_ identities like these, it is usually easier to go the other way; multiply out those parentheses and compare. There are often less subtleties involved going in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

given $$abc +abc'+bcd$$ $$ab(1+c') +bcd$$ since $1+c'=1$$$ab+bcd$$ $$b(a+cd)$$ using the distributive law $a+cd=(a+c)(a+d)$ gives you $$b(a+c)(a+d)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Express both sides of the equation in form of minterms (terms containing all variables). This can be done by multiplying by $(x+\bar{x})$ where $x$ is the missing variable in a term.